# TypeScript class declaration error with private variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

If I have a TypeScript class declaration like this:

```
export class myClass {
  constructor(public aVariable: number) {}
  private aPrivateVariable: number;
}
```

and then try to initialize it with:

```
let someVar: myClass[] = [{
  aVariable: 3
}, {
  aVariable: 2
}];
```

I get an error (at least in VS Code) saying:

Property 'aPrivateVariable' is missing in type '{ aVariable: number; }'.

Why can't I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine your class also has a method that uses this field:

```
 export class myClass {
  constructor(public aVariable: number) {}
  private aPrivateVariable: number;
  test(){  }
 }
```

Now if you would do the following:

```
 const instance: myClass = {
    aVariable: 1,
    test() {
      alert.aPrivateVariable + 1);
    }
 };

 instance.test();
```

It would fail. Therefore, you also need to add private properties.

```
 let someVar: myClass[] = [{
  aVariable: 3,
  aPrivateVariable: 2,
 }, {
  aVariable: 2,
  aPrivateVariable: 3
 }];
```

Comment: Your suggestion won't work ([`private` variables](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#understanding-private) cannot be referenced from outside the class); have you tried it?

Comment: @Jonas W - I know, that's what I'm trying to avoid. I want this class to have a couple of internal variables that the initializer of the class will not need to reference or declare. So that the private variable is for internal use only.

Comment: @mike then make it optional.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer because this is what I did. The class is very light weight and I did not want to create an interface for it.

Comment: @MikeWitt How exactly did you make it work, by the way? The answer contains non-workable code. As it was mentioned, you can't assign `aPrivateVariable` from the outside... because it's *private* (this property of TS types can be used to make types deliberately incompatible) . If your code differs from the one that was listed, consider posting the solution you ended with. This may help future readers.

Comment: @estus - Sorry, it was the comment to make the fields optional. I still think the answer with using a Interface was better, but it is really just a struct and not a class.

Comment: @MikeWitt I see. Glad you sorted this out.

Answer (score 1):

Type `{ aVariable: number; }` isn't compatible with `myClass`

As [the manual](http://private-and-protected-members-in-classes) states,

> Private and protected members in a class affect their compatibility. When an instance of a class is checked for compatibility, if the target type contains a private member, then the source type must also contain a private member that originated from the same class. Likewise, the same applies for an instance with a protected member. This allows a class to be assignment compatible with its super class, but not with classes from a different inheritance hierarchy which otherwise have the same shape.

If `myClass` is supposed to be *used as interface* to assign plain objects that are structurally compatible with `myClass` class, separate interface should be provided:

```
interface IMyClass {
  aVariable: number;
}

export class myClass implements IMyClass {...}

let someVar: IMyClass[] = [{
  aVariable: 3
}];
```

> and then try to initialize it

It should be noticed that the code above doesn't *initialize* the class. It's unclear what were the reasons to assign plain objects instead of class instances, but if `someVar` should contain instances of `myClass`, type error indicates the problem. Instances should be explicitly instantiated with `new`:

```
let someVar: myClass[] = [new myClass(3)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining the objects in the way you did (`{ aVariable: 2}`) does not instantiate them as `myClass` objects. This is a problem since `aPrivateVariable` is not being instantiated because `myClass` constructor is never called and the object you add does not match what `myClass` contains.

[As this excerpt from the typescript handbook on type compatibility states](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html):

> Private and protected members in a class affect their compatibility. When an instance of a class is checked for compatibility, if the target type contains a private member, then the source type must also contain a private member that originated from the same class. Likewise, the same applies for an instance with a protected member. This allows a class to be assignment compatible with its super class, but not with classes from a different inheritance hierarchy which otherwise have the same shape.

One way to deal with this is to instantiate every object using something such as `map()`

`const someVar: myClass[] = [2,3,1].map(num => myClass(num)) ;`

Or, if you're confident of the shape of the object, you can use type coercion:

`let someVar: myClass[] = [] as myClass[]`

Be careful with this approach though since it does not guarantee that what's contained in the array matches the model of the class.

Answer (score 1):

```
export class myClass {
   constructor(public aVariable: number) {}
   private aPrivateVariable: number;
}
```

The correct way would be really initializing your class like this:

```
const someVar: myClass[] = [
    new myClass(3),
    new myClass(2),
]
```

If you don't initialize your class then you want to get any methods from `myClass`, you will end up with object cast as `myClass`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare the class. You can do it like this

```
const someVar: myClass[] = [new myClass(3), new myClass(2)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to initialize this class is -

```
export class myClass {
  constructor(public aVariable: number) {}
  private aPrivateVariable: number;
}

let someVar: myClass = new myClass(3);
```